# Ubuntu 19.04 Installer Will not Recognize Win 10 for Dual Boot Install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

Im new to Linux and know almost nothing about bootloaders and BIOS. Im trying to install Ubuntu 19.04 on my win10 machine, but after 7 hours have been unable to install, as Ubuntu will not recognize that win10 exists on the filesystem and will only allow the Erase option.

I have gone into the BIOS and played with every combination of settings that have been mentioned on several guides/questions relating to this problem

What im Trying to install:
Ubuntu 19.04 from a USB drive (called Ubuntu amdx64)

What im trying to install on:
Windows 10 version 1903 Build 18362.388

I formatted the drive with Rufus using both of the following settings
[Rufus settings 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCeuq.png)
[Rufus settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iY4N9.png)

Things that have been done since I started:
Disabled Fast Boot
Disabled Fast Startup in Win10
Made sure C: drive was error free and ran chkdsk

I have performed any combination of:

Enable/Disabled CSM
Enable/Disabled Secure Boot, as well as loading/unloading dbs
Enable/Disable Windows UEFI booting (Switching between Windows UEFI and "Other OS")
Changed bios load order

Here are my system specs
[My machine info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh2x8.jpg)

As noted i have looked through several guides but still i cant make them coexist at all.

Thank you for any and all responses

EDITS: changed out machine info screenshot as it did not load properly

Comment: The window which says erase everything, does it contain an option saying `Something else' ?

Answer (score 0):

You can install GParted using `sudo apt install gparted`, then launch it using `sudo gparted`.

Make sure that your disk is selected, then resize the windows partition to the size that you want. Then move to the unallocated space and press **format to ext4 filesystem**.

After that, return to the ubuntu installer and do the necessary steps. When you reach the install menu, press **custom install** and select the partition that you just formatted to ext4. Then wait for the installation process to complete.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you already have Ubuntu 19.04 on USB you should be able to boot it using the **Try Ubuntu without installing** option.

Once Ubuntu is loaded, go to **Show Applications** --> **Disks**. Resize your Windows partition to create an unallocated partition of (ideally) at least 25 GB.

Format the **unallocated** space to **Ext4 Filesystem**.

Install Ubuntu with either **Install Ubuntu** icon on Desktop (highly recommended) or reboot and follow the normal process.

Make sure you use the **custom install** option and select the **Ext4** partition that you just formatted.

Wait for the installation to complete and you are done!

Comment: There's nothing to disagree with here except that the recommended size is of the Ubuntu partition is at least 25GB.